# Error with python code read from sqs and writing to dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Use case:

1. Read JSON SQS messages via lambda function(written in python).
2. Write JSON message to dynamodb.

I have created a queue, a lambda function(python code below) and a dynamodb table . I have attached the lambda function to SQS.
This works fine (row gets added to dynamodb) when I test by using data from test event.

Issue is: 
To test triggering of lambda, I added following JSON data to the sqs queue-manually, but no data is getting inserted into dynamodb.

```
{"FirstName":"Name1SQS","City": "City1SQS"}
```

I have tested the python function by configuring a test event.  This works fine and creates a json record in dynamodb. It seems that variable message is correctly getting/processing data in JSON format from the test event but not from SQS.

Code for lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):

message =  event['Records'][0]['body']

dynamodb_table_name = dynamodb.Table('Lead')
dynamodb_table_name.put_item(
    Item=message
)
```

I get this error in Cloudwatch logs when I create new SQS message manually.

*[ERROR] ParamValidationError Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Item*

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: mostly you would be putting json with one key's value as null. Null are not allowed to be put in dynamodb

Comment: sorry I'm not able to follow. Could you please provide suggestions to my code?

Comment: try logging message before inserting in dynamodb, and then debug.

Comment: I did that. Here is the messege/print outout just before the put_item command.              {'FirstName':'Name3SQS','City': 'City3SQS'}

Comment: and this failed? what is your table schema?

Comment: Yes. Just 3 columns - FirstName, City, LastName. FirstName being the key. It did not fail when I was testing via the test event. But failed when processing the SQS message.